# Redirecting ports for a service can iptables be used instead of mod_proxy

Tags: unix, jira, iptables, mod-proxy, masking

I have a service which is running on http port 8080 and https port 8443 and all traffic to port 8080 is being redirected to https 8443 which is configured on server.xml itself.

Requirement :

All traffic when using ports 80,8080,443,8443 should be diverted to 8443 without port number getting displayed under URL

Possible solutions :

I know that using mod_proxy,masking and reverse proxy we can implement it (http://www.pothireddy.com/knowledge/environment/masking/)

---

Question here is can we use IPTABLES to implement that instead of mod_proxy solution, if so how can do we achieve it....

Already tried something like this :

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
Fixed problem when someone is hitting port 443

1. When someone hits port 8443 explicitly then port 8443 is showing
   up on the url ? Can we implement something like .... just to mask
   the port 8443 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 -j
   REDIRECT --to-port 8443
2. How to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 8443, when I tried
   using below command, looks like it is getting confused diverting
   traffic from http port to https port ? iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING
   -p tcp --dport 8443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

Any Possible solution for fixing the above 2 questions ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache web-server, you can make new virtualhost in some port like 
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure:8443
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```